# Using mailchimp API in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to send mail to my all users with his blog post using mailchimp API in laravel 5.2. And application will send mail frequently 30 minutes later after.

How will I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to done two task:
**1)** Setup mail with mailchimp(Third party API) and
**2)** use that setup for [laravel schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling)
to send periodic(Every 30 min) mail.

You can use [mailchimp-api](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) as Third party API. Follow given instruction for complete mailchimp configuration.

Comment: will it take my all users from database? Or I have to make subscription list in mailchimp?

Comment: @Md.HabiburRahman Yes, if you want to use(To send) mailchimp you need subscription list from mailchimp

Comment: @Md.HabiburRahman Further you can get more idea about[Send mail from mailchimp](http://laraveldaily.com/send-mailchimp-email-campaigns-from-laravel/)

Comment: @Md.HabiburRahman If you got the solution then request to upvote OR place if any doubt with same